# Documenting bash functions

Tags: bash, manpage

I would like to add documentation for bash functions so that users can lookup the functions with `man`. There should be no visible difference between my functions and actual commands.

I know I can do this by overriding `man` with a function that checks for my own functions. Is there another way?

Comment: Are we talking about _real_ shell _functions_ which are defined with `foo(){ echo foo; }` or are we talking about _programs_ (which _may_ be implemented by a shell script) which are installed somewhere in a `*/bin` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real shell functions are **not** documented by individual `man` pages but by the `help` builtin command. You would have to override that. But even I would not look there for information.

Just generate normal man pages and throw them into `/usr/local/man/manX` or `/usr/local/share/man/manX` - whatever your distribution already provides. Check `/etc/manpath.config` that this directory is already mentioned there. That way no one must fiddle in their startup files with the `MANPATH` environment variable.

Each manpage should also contain a clearly visible section explaining, that this is a *function* and not a *command* and what the difference is.

After that the social part kicks in: Tell everyone at *every* occasion about that documetation. By *every* I mean *every*, not only *suitable*. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you have your man pages created (which is a task in itself) then what you can do is put them somewhere on the system like `/usr/local/man` (or wherever you like, really), then edit the system-wide `$MANPATH` variable to include that location. Then the man pages will be available.